# CParserError: Error tokenizing data. when reading book-crossing dataset

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to read [book-crossing dataset](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ecziegler/BX/) table: BX-Books. using pandas.
When I write:

```
  #load book informations dataset
books = pd.read_csv("BX-CSV-Dump/BX-Books.csv",sep=';')
```

I get an error:

> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 6452, saw 9

How to correct this? I tried with '\t' as a separator but it didn't work too, I get all the columns in one column separated by "`;`" in that case.

Comment: Did you go to line 6452 and see what your data looks like and why it throws that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the strings like:

```
"Peterman Rides Again: Adventures Continue with the Real \"J. Peterman\" Through Life &amp; the Catalog Business"
```

NOTE: pay attention at `&amp;`, containing the `;` and `\"J. Peterman\"`, containing the quote character

So try this:

```
In [34]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=';', escapechar='\\', encoding='CP1252', 
                          low_memory=False)

In [35]: df.shape
Out[35]: (271379, 8)
```

Comment: I got many lines skipped. what's the reason? I mean, I want to understand what makes using ';' as delimiter unsuccessful?  Thank you.

Comment: Somehow, yes..but how is that while there is the same number of columns for all lines.. ok, If I don't want lines to be skipped, should I use another library to read the file? what is it?

Comment: @SarahM, i've just found out the "right approach" ;-)